# How do I create a User-managed Cloud Platform project?

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script inside a Google Docs document. I want to use it in all my docs documents, so inside the script editor I clicked Publish -> Deploy as Docs add-on...

However, the following alert prompts:

[image: Alert]

What should I do in order to use my script?

Comment: Did you try clicking the hyperlink (the blue text) for instructions on how to switch to a user-managed Cloud Platform project?

Comment: I did Dimu! It takes me to some documentation explaining what is it talking about. But not explanation about what to do now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please check out the instructions that have been documented under:

[Google Cloud Platform Projects > **Switching to a different standard GCP project**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).

Sharing the steps here too, for reference:

1. Create a new Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project - instructions available [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project) if you don't already have one.

- in case you already have a GCP project configured, switch to that project via the cloud console.

2. Get the Project ID/number - instructions available [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#determining_the_id_and_number_of_a_standard_gcp_project)
3. Then go back to your script from the Apps Script browser editor and navigate to **Resources > Cloud Platform project**
4. In the **Change Project** section, paste the project number you copied into the text field, then click **Set Project** & finally **Confirm** on the subsequent page.

Personally, I had difficulties following through step 2 i.e. getting the project number so here's where you find it -

[image: project number]

Comment: thank you man! the resources were too long to just perform this simple task....